# Assistance on Python Rock, Paper, Scissors using input file

Tags: python

I am trying to take a file that has a number on the first line that determines how many hands of rock paper scissors are played. It looks something like this.

```
3
Rock Paper
Paper Rock
Scissors Scissors
```

I'm supposed to write something that shows who won the hand. Here's what I have come up with so far. (I am extremely new to python coming off a 2 year break from school so I apologize for any ignorance.)

Thank you

```
def RockPaperScissors (filename):


    f_in = open(filename , 'r')
    nTimes = int(f_in.readline())
    playerA = ' '
    playerB = ''
    for x in range(nTimes):
        choices = f_in.readline().split()
        playerA = choices[0:1]
        playerB= choices[-1:]

        if playerA == 'Rock'and playerB == 'Paper':
            print 'PlayerB Won!'
        if playerA == 'Rock'and playerB == 'Scissors':
            print 'PlayerA Won!'
        if playerA == 'Paper' and playerB == 'Rock':
            print 'PlayerA Won!'
        if playerA == 'Paper' and playerB == 'Scissors':
            print 'PlayerB Won!'
        if playerA == 'Scissors'and playerB == 'Paper':
            print 'PlayerA Won'
        if playerA == 'Scissors'and playerB == 'Rock':
            print 'PlayerB Won'
        else:
            print 'Tie!'
    return 

RockPaperScissors ('RockPaperScissors.txt')
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your question should state the problem you're having with the code you post. Ideally, you should also show the _expected_ output of the code, and the _actual_ output.

Answer (score 2):

You're close. You're slicing `choices`, which means `playerA` and `playerB` are one-element lists. You don't need to slice `choices`; just get the values by index.

```
playerA = choices[0]
playerB = choices[1]
```

Or better yet, do this:

```
playerA, playerB = choices
```

Answer (score 2):

Cyphase has shown how to get the strings you want into `playerA` & `playerB`.

When writing a program it's generally a Good Idea to print your input variables to make sure they contain what you expect them to contain. Eg, if you did `print playerA, playerB` just after the `playerB= choices[-1:]` line then you would've seen that `playerA` & `playerB` each held a single element list instead of a string.

But your program has another problem: you need to change your `if` test section. If any of the first 5 `if` tests is true then the appropriate message is printed, but the program then goes on to make all the other tests. They will all be false. And that includes the last `if` test, so its `else` part will be executed and so `Tie!` gets printed.

To fix that, you need to turn the `if`s after the first one into `elif`s, like this:

```
if playerA == 'Rock' and playerB == 'Paper':
    print 'PlayerB Won!'
elif playerA == 'Rock' and playerB == 'Scissors':
    print 'PlayerA Won!'
elif playerA == 'Paper' and playerB == 'Rock':
    print 'PlayerA Won!'
elif playerA == 'Paper' and playerB == 'Scissors':
    print 'PlayerB Won!'
elif playerA == 'Scissors' and playerB == 'Paper':
    print 'PlayerA Won'
elif playerA == 'Scissors' and playerB == 'Rock':
    print 'PlayerB Won'
else:
    print 'Tie!'
```

There are other ways to organize those tests that are more compact, but this organization is straight-forward and easy to read.

Comment: Ok perfect thank you so much for the help. I have figured it out.

Comment: @CollegeNewbie: You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of these answers to let people know that your problem has been resolved.